# Getting cannot read property 'users' of undefined while creating mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to create a mongoose model and using it to get the data from the mongodb, but I am getting the exception

My mongoose version from package.json is :**"mongoose": "4.5.5"**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined
```

Now here is my demo code:

```
var mongoose  =   require("mongoose");
var schema    =   mongoose.Schema;
var Users = {
    _id         :   {
        type        :   String,
        require     :   true
    },
    username    :   {
        type        :   String,
        required    :   true
    },
    password    :   {
        type        :   String,
        required    :   true
    }
};
var UsersModel  =   new mongoose.model('users', Users);
var newUser = new UsersModel({"username":"A", "password":"V"});
newUser.save(function(err, result){
    if(err){
        console.log('>>>>>> Error');
    }else{
        console.log('>>>>>> ' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
    }
});
```

And here is the error :

```
/home/ankur/Private/Work/ps/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:343
if (!this.modelSchemas[name]) {                                                                         
                        ^                                                                                 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined                                                      
    at new Mongoose.model (/home/ankur/Private/Work/ps/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:343:25)         
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ankur/Private/Work/ps/models_mongoose/Users.model.js:24:21)              
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)                                                                 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)                                                   
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)                                                                     
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)                                                           
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)                                                         
    at startup (node.js:119:16)                                                                           
    at node.js:929:3
```

Now my question is in this code I have hardly done anything extra, just configured the schema, created a new model on that schema and saved it.
So where I missed the stuff?

Please shed some views.

Comment: I think `var Users = {...}` should be `var Users = mongoose.Schema({...})`. Did you try that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have few errors. I've attached fully working example:

```js
var mongoose  =   require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name'); //you need open to connection - this is an example of valid connection string

var Schema    =   mongoose.Schema;
var Users = new Schema({ // example from docs
    _id         :   {
        type        :   String,
        require     :   true
    },
    username    :   {
        type        :   String,
        required    :   true
    },
    password    :   {
        type        :   String,
        required    :   true
    }
});
var UsersModel = mongoose.model('users_test', Users); //remove 'new' keyword
var newUser = new UsersModel({"username":"A", "password":"V", "_id": 0}); // you also need here to define _id since, since you set it as required.
newUser.save(function(err, result){
    if(err){
        console.log('>>>>>> Error');
    }else{
        console.log('>>>>>> ' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
    }
});
```

To sum up:

1. You should to make connection by calling `connect` method on `mongoose` object
2. Use `new Schema` constructor while creating model
3. Remove `new` keyword from `var UsersModel = mongoose.model(...)`
4. Add `_id` key with value, because without that you will get error that this value is missing

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up Schema and model.

```
var mongoose  =   require("mongoose");
var Schema    =   mongoose.Schema;
var Users = new Schema({ // add schema here!
  _id         :   {
    type        :   String,
    require     :   true
  },
  username    :   {
    type        :   String,
    required    :   true
  },
  password    :   {
    type        :   String,
    required    :   true
  }
});
var UsersModel  =  mongoose.model('users', Users); // remove new here!
var newUser = new UsersModel({"username":"A", "password":"V"});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try...
:) +1

Answer (score 1):

If you're coming from google - make sure your imports are correct. Webstorm will auto-import with `import mongoose from 'mongoose';` but you need `import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';`