# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') when posting to mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

ERROR:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
const newItem = new items({
    name: req.body.name
})

try {
    const submitted = await items.save();
    console.log(submitted);
}
catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
})
```

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

 const pieces = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
 })

 module.exports = mongoose.model("items", pieces);




//index
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv/config");

const product = require("../backend/Router/productRoutes");

app.use("/add", product);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB, () => {
    console.log("DB CONNECTED")
});

app.listen(3500, () => {
    console.log("server up");
});
```

this same code works in another project so I'm confused as to what's going on here. I tried almost every suggestion but nothing works.

Comment: Would this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960674/getting-cannot-read-property-users-of-undefined-while-creating-mongoose-model

Comment: The error is probably saying that `req.body` is undefined, which means you're not using a body parser middleware (properly).

Comment: add `app.use(express.json())` in your index.js before making any endpoint call

Comment: I did nothing works.. I updated my post to include more code

Comment: I was calling on my route first and then body-parsers when the route is supposed to come last

Answer (score 0):

You need a body parsing middleware that will read a form's input and store it as a javascript object accessible through `req.body`.

Install [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser), it is a middleware that parses incoming request bodies in order to read HTTP POST data.

```
$ npm install body-parser
```

Then, import it in the index.js file

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
```

and add this line:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```